Pandas dataframe to yaml preserving hierarchy
I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'title':['dashboard1','dashboard1','dashboard2']
               ,'srv':['ods','ods','ods']
               ,'db':['db1','db1','db2']
               ,'sch':['S1','S2','S4']
               ,'nm':['Name1','Name2','Name3']})
df

I want to convert this dataframe to the following YAMLs:
title: dashboard1
dataSources:
  dataObjects:
    -srv:ods
     db:db1
     sch:S1
     nm:Name1
    -srv:ods
     db:db1
     sch:S2
     nm:Name2

title: dashboard2
dataSources:
  dataObjects:
    -srv:ods
     db:db2
     sch:S4
     nm:Name3    

I tried using
yaml.dump({'dataObjects': df.groupby('title')['nm'].apply(list).to_dict()},allow_unicode=True)

to no avail.
Could someone be so kind as to give me some hints which method to look at to perform this transformation?

With groupby/to_dict("records") and dump_all :
print(
    yaml.dump_all(
        [
            {"title": t, "dataSources": {"dataObjects": ele}}
            for t, ele in df.groupby("title", sort=False)
            .apply(lambda g: g.to_dict("records"), include_groups=False)
            .to_dict()
            .items()
        ],
        sort_keys=False,
    ).replace("---", "")
)

Output :
title: dashboard1
dataSources:
  dataObjects:
  - srv: ods
    db: db1
    sch: S1
    nm: Name1
  - srv: ods
    db: db1
    sch: S2
    nm: Name2

title: dashboard2
dataSources:
  dataObjects:
  - srv: ods
    db: db2
    sch: S4
    nm: Name3


This throws the following error:
TypeError: () got an unexpected keyword argument 'include_groups'
Aside from that, this seems to work. Thanks!

I'm using 2.2.2. If you're using an older one, replace my apply with this one : .apply(lambda g: g.drop(columns="title").to_dict("records")).
